# How to extract files from .a(Static Library) in iOS development?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to extract implementation files from the static library.

Thanks,

Comment: Oh god save him #[Reverse Engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering#Reverse_engineering_of_software)

Comment: This is so inhuman...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can do this I have read somewhere you can do that by otool -tV  from terminal. Or may be try [hopperapp](http://hopperapp.com/)